# SQL Server transpose (pivot) table with data aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

I have a quick question. I want the DELTA between one column with a different PK.

I have this table structure in my database:

```
RecordID  | Time | ColA | ColB | ColC
    1     | 2016 |  1   |  1   |  2
    1     | 2017 |  2   |  3   |  2
    2     | 2016 |  4   |  1   |  1
    2     | 2017 |  2   |  1   |  1
```

PK: RecordID and Time.

And what I want to see is this:

```
ColName |  Time  |  Delta
ColA    |  2016  |   -3
ColA    |  2017  |   0
ColB    |  2016  |   0
ColB    |  2017  |   2
ColC    |  2016  |   1
ColC    |  2017  |   1
```

Basically: ColA from 2016 and RecordID 1 minus ColA from 2017 and Record 2

It would be great if it’s possible to create something like that in a view or stored procedure.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  First, unpivot the table to get the records in a more manageable form.  Then self-join such that you join to the previous entry in recordID with the same time and column name.  I think this is reasonably scalable.  I am no SQL expert, but this seems to get the job done.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT * FROM test
UNPIVOT (
    Value FOR column_name IN
    (ColA, COlB, COlC)
)AS unpvt
)

SELECT  CTE1.column_name, 
        CTE1.time, 
        CTE1.value - CTE2.value AS Delta
FROM CTE AS CTE1
INNER JOIN CTE AS CTE2
ON CTE2.time = CTE1.time
AND cte1.column_name = cte2.column_name
AND CTE1.recordID = CTE2.recordID - 1
```